# Ошибка "ClassNotFoundError" в onCreate методе Activity

Tags: android

Почему выскакивает ошибка `ClassNotFoundError`? До этого ее не было.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу строку

```
    at com.example.prostopost.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
```

Вот и смотрите, что у вас в 27 строке, а именно в методе onCreate(). Если меня не обманывает зрение, то по каким-то причинам не удается найти класс TempData в пакете com.example.prostopost. У вас скорее всего в 27 строке выполняется метод, использующий экземпляр класса TempData, но самого файла TempData.java нету.  
У меня к вам вопрос: вы пишете прямо на смартфоне?

Comment: Да, на смартфоне. Я уже нашел решение. Нужно было прописать полный путь к классу в манифесте.

Comment: >вы пишете прямо на телефоне?

Ну а почему бы и [нет](http://i.imgur.com/u5KrXB1)? :P

*поскорее бы доделать клиент, а то с этой разметкой не совладать*

Comment: @SuperCreeper, мсье знает толк в извращениях